# Send message via websocket on a timer

Tags: node.js, websocket

I've got my server set up, now I just want to send a message every 60 seconds. How do I send a message in another function? I'd like to write something like function gameLoop(){ someobject.send(myMessage); } but if that's the case, then what would someobject.send(myMessage) be?

```
var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
  console.log((new Date()) + ' Received request for ' + request.url);
  response.writeHead(404);
  response.end();
});
server.listen(3001, function() {
  console.log((new Date()) + ' Server is listening on port 3001');
});

wsServer = new WebSocketServer({
  httpServer: server,
  // You should not use autoAcceptConnections for production applications
  autoAcceptConnections: false
});

function originIsAllowed(origin) {
  // put logic here to detect whether the specified origin is allowed.
  return true;
}

wsServer.on('request', function(request) {
  if (!originIsAllowed(request.origin)) {
    request.reject();
    console.log((new Date()) + ' Connection from origin ' + request.origin + ' rejected.');
    return;
  }

  var connection = request.accept('echo-protocol', request.origin);
  console.log((new Date()) + ' Connection accepted.');
  connection.on('message', function(message) {
    if (message.type === 'utf8') {
      console.log('Received Message: ' + message.utf8Data);
      if(message.utf8Data == "Map?") {
        connection.send(JSON.stringify(map));
      }
    }
  });
  connection.on('close', function(reasonCode, description) {
    console.log((new Date()) + ' Peer ' + connection.remoteAddress + ' disconnected.');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For sending message you have to use: 
`wsServer.sendMessage(people, data, id)`.
Thus you need `wsServer` object in your gameloop() function. As alternative you can set wsServer to global object in node.js as: `global.wsServer = wsServer`. And access it as `global.wsServer.sendMessage("one", "Game Over", id)`

Comment: My IDE is saying that global.wsServer.sendMessage() is an unresolved function  or method.

Comment: did you set the `global.wsServer = wsServer` after you create `var wsServer = new WebSocketServer({...})`

Comment: After adding that to the code, I now get: TypeError: undefined is not a function on the .send() function. I'm using the websocket v1.0.22 package.